# Proportion of Prime Gaps Divisible by n (expected)?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

We seem to know that the proportion of prime gaps divisible by 6 (as the gaps tend toward infinity) ≈ 1/2. Are we able to find the expected proportion of prime gaps divisible by 4, or 8, or 10?

Comment: What is your guess ? Why do you think $6$ is different to $4$ or $8$ ?

Comment: @reuns I would guess that it depends on the number of factors that it has. Is there any way to generalize an "exact" proportion like we do for 6? It seems that it's also about 1/2 for 4.

Comment: Why do you think $6$ is special and why do you think in that case it is $1/2$ ?

Comment: It is a consequence of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression that given a natural number $n$, primes are evenly distributed amongst the residue classes prime to $n$. So the proportion of the differences between primes which are divisible by $n$ would tend to $\varphi (n)$ (because this happens just when they are in the same residue class modulo $n$) - of course most of these differences are not gaps, and we don't even know whether there are infinitely many twin primes (gap $2$). Where did you find the information about $6$?